# Why are HttpWebRequest and WebBrowser getting different HTML source code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, browser

I am trying to get the source code from a webpage. The WebBrowser control is giving me the information that I am looking for. However, I want to use HttpWebRequest, but its giving me different source code than the WebBrowser DocumentText.

Can anyone please tell me how can I get the same source code as WebBrowser using HttpWebRequest?

**WebBrowser Code:**

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/results.jsp?domain=" & txtUrl.Text)
textbox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText
```

**WebBrowser Result:**

http://textbin.com/f4368

**HttpWebRequest Code:**

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
request.KeepAlive = False
request.Timeout = 10000

Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim sourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
```

**HttpWebRequest Result:**

http://textbin.com/2h445

Answer (score 4):

Some sites will look at the user-agent string or other factors and return content that varies based on this. I've written a number of projects that downloaded web pages and have run into this a few times.

Comment: Also, WebBrowser executes javascript that may modify the DOM.

Comment: To solve a problem with this root cause, you could run a tool like Fiddler to examine the difference between your requests.  Then you can try to tweak your user-agent/headers/referrer, etc to match

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. I have added User Agent as you said and its working now. Here is the code I have used: Http.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)"

Answer (score 0):

This is an old-ish question but the reason this happens is that MSHTML - the Windows html rendering engine - modifies the incoming HTML before it renders it.  You can change the rendering mode of the .NET web browser to use any of IE7, 8, or 9 rendering engines and you'll see HUGE differences in the HTML they return back out of the browser - IE9's is going to be the most similar to what you see come down in HttpWebRequest.